# Adding streamlit to anaconda leads to Segmentation Fault:11

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, streamlit

I'd like to run streamlit locally. I have anaconda on my MacOS (runnning el capitan) and I attempted to add streamlit by following the instructions found here:

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/troubleshooting/clean-install.html#install-streamlit-on-macos-linux

I get no errors on the install. When I run

```
streamlit hello
```

I get a segmentation fault (Segmentation fault: 11). I cant't attach the full error output as it goes over the 30K character limit.

P.S: Thank you for your advice. This is the first of what I hope are many posts contributing to the community. I've been a lurker for a while and benefited from the previous answers posted here. I've asked around for help with this issue and it might be something new. In any case I appreciate your aid on solving this problem, as streamlit does in fact seem pretty lit (I'm a begginer and it is a great starting point).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you. I want to install and run streamlit locally on my macOS laptop. I followed the instructions on the streamlit website for doing so, and I got no errors. However, I get a seg fault when trying to run streamlit afterwards. I have no clue what's wrong.